# Create forms according to the user action. But not at once

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I have to build a form like so.

This shows upfront. i.e. without user interaction.

[image]

When a user pressed the + button it creates the same kind of UI again like so.

[image]

You can see that the user can add any number of same UI parts again and again. Can you tell me how to do this?

I went through number of articles. But it has the whole form created once. i.e. not like my use case. Any direction for this?

Example: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/25/angular-8-dynamic-reactive-forms-example

and https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Comment: You need FormArray https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Comment: @MsuArven Yes, I went through that too. But I have a fixed set of form control names no. So how can I apply that? And the article where it created upfront too. i.e. not like my use case.

Comment: The example is exactly your use case : you create a function returning a new formgroup with your fixed form controls and another one to push this new formgroup to the formarray. Finally you just need to call the last function with your 'add' button

Comment: @GérômeGrignon Please give pseudo kind of implementation on the answer section. That will really help me.

Comment: Is all this going to be a single form? or it is collection of different small forms?

Comment: @Plochie I need to save all data using the `Save` button. So it would be nice if I have 1 form. Any clue?

Comment: Thanks. It seems no different than the normal way. Since I have never done this kind of thing I thought it will have a different approach. I'll try that. @Plochie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the form you need to reproduce :

Create a function returning a formGroup to populate your array

```
createSchoolPath(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    schoolName: '',
    level: '',
    topics: [],
    inProgress: true
})
}
```

You then need to create your parent form which include your form array (and populate it once for the first form you want to show upfront) :

```
constructor( private fb: formBuilder) {}

form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  schoolPaths: this.fb.array([this.createSchoolPaths])
});
```

Finally as you want to let users add more sections, you need a way to populate your array :

```
/* component */

addSchoolPath(): void {
  const paths = this.form.get('schoolPaths') as FormArray;
  // use the first function to push a new formGroup
  paths.push(this.createSchoolPath());
}

<!-- html -->
<button (click)="addSchoolPath()">+</button>
```

To display it :

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="schoolPaths" *ngFor="let path of form.get('schoolPaths').controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <!-- place your inputs here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<button (click)="addSchoolPath()">+</button>
```

Comment: This seems great. I'll try that and come back. One question. Can you tell me how to get all those values to `Save` button? i.e. I need to save all at once.

Comment: you'll get the result with `this.form.value.schoolPaths` as an array in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To complementary Gérôme's answer, you can also use directly a formArray

```
createGroup()
{
   return new FormGroup({
      school:new FormControl(),
      level:new FormControl(),
      topic:new FormControl(),
      progress:new FormControl()
   })
}
```

At first you has a formArray

```
formArray:FormArray=new FormArray([this.createGroup()])
```

The add button is simple

```
add()
{
   this.formArray.push(this.createGroup())
}
```

And the .html

```
<form [formGroup]="formArray">
   <div *ngFor="let group of formArray.controls" [formGroup]="group">
      <input formControlName="school">
      <input formControlName="level">
      <input formControlName="topic">
      <input formControlName="progress">
   </div>
</form>
```

See that, in general we use a formArray inside a formGroup, But in case you only want a FormArray, you can loop over the formArray.controls directly